# Как правильно организовать работу с данными (C# Desktop App, Database)?

Tags: c#, sqlite, desktop

Упрощенная схема БД
[image: упрощенная схема данных]

Нужна помощь в организации работы с данными.
Сабжект: десктопное приложение для гостиницы. 
В таблице Reservations данные по каждому размещению. Каждое размещение может состоять из одного или нескольких дней (ResDays). На каждый день размещения может быть добавлена доп. услуга (AddServices).

В программе для этого я использую коллекции. Очень упрощенно:

```
class AddServiceItem
{
   string Name;
   Decimal Cost;
}
class ResDayItem
{
   DateTime Date;
   Decimal Cost;
   Collection<AddServiceItem> AddServices;
}
class Reservation
{
   DateTime StartDate;
   DateTime StartDate;
   int Status;
   Collection<ResDayItem> ResDays;
}
```

С созданием размещения проблем нет - пользователь выбирает количество дней, создается экземпляр Reservation, а коллекции из дней и доп. услуг заполняются юзером в интерфейсе программы. После нажатия кнопки "Добавить размещение" все записывается в БД.

Конечно, нужно иметь возможность изменять все данные. При открытии размещения для редактирования, я опять создаю экземпляр Reservation, а коллекции заполняю значениями из БД примерно так

```
MyReservation = new Reservation();
//создаю коллекцию дней
MyReservation.ResDays = new Collection<ResDayItem>();
//и для каждого дня размещения с Id == resId
foreach (var Day in db.Table<ResDays>().Where(x => x.ResId == resId))
{   //создаю экземпляр ResDayItem
    ResDayItem DayItem = new ReservationDayItem();
  //и в нем коллекцию доп. услуг
  DayItem.AddServices = new Collection<AddServItem>();
    foreach (var AddService in db.Table<AddServices>().Where(x => x.ResDayId == Day.Id))
        DayItem.AddServices.Add(AddService);
    MyReservation.ResDays.Add(DayItem);
}
```

Вопрос в следующем: как (в каком порядке) делать апдейт БД при изменении коллекций?
Хотелось бы, чтобы в БД все писалось при нажатии пользователем кнопки "Сохранить". Если количество дней/доп.услуг осталось прежним, то это просто update по всем записям, а если юзер удалил что-то? Как узнать, какие именно элементы коллекций были удалены, чтобы удалить соответствующие записи из БД?
Может быть я вообще применил неверный подход с такой вложенностью коллекций?
Как правильно организовать работу с данными в такой задаче?

Comment: Вы используете какую-нибудь ORM? Если да, то почему нельзя вызвать какой-нибудь SaveChanges у контекста?

Comment: если вы используйте EntityFramework, то достаточно из вашего DbSet<T> удалить нужный объект и вызвать Db.SaveChanges(), если нет - самое время начать его использовать

Comment: @Arthur из приведенного кода видно, что человек не использует ORM

Comment: @kingwsf Каким образом вы взаимодействуете с источником данных? ADO.NET?

Comment: @AndreiS. из приведенного кода явно видно, что человек использует ORM :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В более-менее сложных программах реализуют примерно такую структуру

[image: 3 слоя приложения]

Как пример реализации паттернов `Repository` и `Unit of Work` могу предложить вам следующий вариант.
Для `Repository` мы будем опираться на следующую иллюстрацию

[image: реализация Repository]

Для `Unit of Work` мы будем опираться на следующую иллюстрацию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1) Создайте проект Class Library `LibDomain`, создайте в нем две папки: Repositories и Models.
2) Cоздайте след. классы в папке Models

```
public class Reservation
{
    //ctor
    public Reservation() => Days = new HashSet<ReservedDay>();

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ReservedDay> Days { get; set; }
}
```

``

```
public class ReservedDay
{
    //ctor
    public ReservedDay() => Services = new HashSet<AdditionService>();

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }

    //внешний ключ
    public long ReservationId { get; set; }
    //навигационное св-во
    public virtual Reservation Reservation { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AdditionService> Services { get; set; }
}
```

``

```
public class AdditionService
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }

    //внешний ключ
    public long ReservedDayId { get; set; }
    //навигационное св-во
    public virtual ReservedDay Day { get; set; }
}
```

``
3) в папке репозиториев вам нужно будет создать главный интерфейс репозитория

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    //Queries
    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> Get();
    Task<TEntity> Get(long id);
    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);

    //Commands
    Task Add(TEntity entity);
    Task AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
    void Remove(TEntity entity);
    void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
}
```

и на каждую сущность свой интерфейса репозитория (даю пример только двух)

```
public interface IReservationRepository : IRepository<Reservation>
{
    //здесь можно добавить объявление необходимых методов
    //актуальных для данной сущности

    Task<Reservation> GetByIdWithDays(long id);

    Task<Reservation> GetByIdWithDaysAndServices(long id);
}
```

``

```
public interface IReservedDayRepository : IRepository<ReservedDay>
{
    //здесь можно добавить объявление необходимых методов
    //актуальных только для данной сущности
}
```

создайте в корне проекта интерфейс для `UnitOfWork`

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IReservationRepository Reservations { get; }
    IReservedDayRepository ReservedDays { get; }
    IAdditionServiceRepository AdditionServices { get; }

    Task<int> Commit();
}
```

4) Создайте в решении еще один проект библиотеки `LibData`, в котором мы непосредственно реализуем работу с `SQLite` через `Entity Framework Core`.
Добавьте ссылку на `LibDomain` и установите через NuGet Package Manager пакет `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` (важно! устанавливайте версию 1.1.2, а не самую последнюю 2.0, которая вышла несколько дней назад, иначе будут проблемы).

5) в проекте создайте класс `SqliteDbContext`

```
public class SqliteDbContext : DbContext
{
    //ctor
    public SqliteDbContext(DbContextOptions<SqliteDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        //создание БД, если она не была ранее создана
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ReservedDay> ReservedDays { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AdditionService> AdditionServices { get; set; }
}
```

и создайте папку Repositories и в ней класс репозитория

```
public abstract class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected readonly DbContext _context;

    //ctor
    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    }

    //Queries
    public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> Get()
    {
        return await _context.Set<TEntity>().ToArrayAsync();
    }

    public virtual async Task<TEntity> Get(long id)
    {
        return await _context.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(id);
    }

    public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return await _context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate).ToArrayAsync();
    }

    //Commands
    public virtual Task Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        return _context.AddAsync(entity);
    }

    public virtual Task AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        return _context.AddRangeAsync(entities);
    }

    public virtual void Remove(TEntity entity)
    {
        _context.Remove(entity);
    }

    public virtual void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        _context.RemoveRange(entities);
    }
}
```

и классы для каждой сущности: `ReservationRepository`, `ReservedDayRepository`, `AdditionServiceRepository` (пример только для первого класса)

```
public class ReservationRepository : Repository<Reservation>, IReservationRepository
{
    private readonly SqliteDbContext _context;

    //ctor
    public ReservationRepository(SqliteDbContext context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    //далее реализация методов из IReservationRepository
    //или переопределение методов из Repository под Reservation

    public Task<Reservation> GetByIdWithDays(long id)
    {
        return _context.Reservations
                            .Include(r => r.Days)
                            .FirstAsync(r => r.Id == id);
    }

    public Task<Reservation> GetByIdWithDaysAndServices(long id)
    {
        return _context.Reservations
                            .Include(r => r.Days)
                            .ThenInclude(d => d.Services)
                            .FirstAsync(r => r.Id == id);
    }
}
```

6) создайте класс, кот. реализутет интерфейс `IUnitOfWork`

```
public class SqliteDataService : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly SqliteDbContext _context;

    //ctor
    public SqliteDataService(SqliteDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        Reservations = new ReservationRepository(_context);
        ReservedDays = new ReservedDayRepository(_context);
        AdditionServices = new AdditionServiceRepository(_context);
    }

    public IReservationRepository Reservations { get; private set; }
    public IReservedDayRepository ReservedDays { get; private set; }
    public IAdditionServiceRepository AdditionServices { get; private set; }


    public Task<int> Commit() => _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    public void Dispose() => _context.Dispose();

    /// <summary>
    /// Соединение с БД и передача экземпляра этого сервиса
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectionString">строка соединения с БД</param>
    /// <returns>экземпляр этого сервиса</returns>
    public static SqliteDataService GetService(string connectionString)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionString));

        var dbBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SqliteDbContext>();
        dbBuilder.UseSqlite(connectionString);

        return new SqliteDataService(new SqliteDbContext(dbBuilder.Options));
    }
}
```

7) Пересмотрите еще раз иллюстрации, перечитайте код примеров. Надеюсь вам станет яснее схема взаимодействия с БД. В качестве примера использования привожу пример простого консольного приложения

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string dbPath = @"Filename=D:\repExample.sqlite";
        var dbService = SqliteDataService.GetService(dbPath);

        //AddReservation(dbService);
        //AddServicesToReservation(dbService);

        ShowReservation(dbService);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async void ShowReservation(SqliteDataService dbService)
    {
        //находим размещение c его днями и услугами по его id
        var res = await dbService.Reservations.GetByIdWithDaysAndServices(1);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"Размещение с {res.StartDate.ToShortDateString()} по {res.EndDate.ToShortDateString()}");
        Console.WriteLine(new string('=', 70));


        int dayNumber = 1;
        int servNumber = 1;
        foreach (var day in res.Days)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"День {dayNumber} - {day.Date.ToShortDateString()}");

            foreach (var service in day.Services)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine($"Услуга {servNumber}:{service.Name} за {service.Cost}руб.");
                servNumber++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 30));
            dayNumber++;
            servNumber = 1;
        }

    }


    private static async void AddReservation(SqliteDataService dbService)
    {
        //создаем дни размещения
        ReservedDay day1 = new ReservedDay()
        {
            Date = new DateTime(year: 2017, month: 8, day: 20),
            Cost = 200M
        };
        ReservedDay day2 = new ReservedDay()
        {
            Date = new DateTime(year: 2017, month: 8, day: 21),
            Cost = 200M
        };
        ReservedDay day3 = new ReservedDay()
        {
            Date = new DateTime(year: 2017, month: 8, day: 22),
            Cost = 200M
        };

        //размещение и его дни
        Reservation res = new Reservation()
        {
            StartDate = day1.Date,
            EndDate = day3.Date,
            Status = 1
        };
        res.Days.Add(day1);
        res.Days.Add(day2);
        res.Days.Add(day3);

        //добавляем и сохраняем в БД
        await dbService.Reservations.Add(res);
        await dbService.Commit();
    }


    private static async void AddServicesToReservation(SqliteDataService dbService)
    {
        var serv1 = new AdditionService { Name = "Бассейн", Cost = 2M };
        var serv2 = new AdditionService { Name = "Парилка", Cost = 1M };
        var serv3 = new AdditionService { Name = "Завтрак в номер", Cost = 100M };
        var serv4 = new AdditionService { Name = "Чай в номер", Cost = 10M };

        //находим размещение по его id
        var res = await dbService.Reservations.GetByIdWithDays(1);

        //выбираем дни по дате
        var dateDay1 = new DateTime(year: 2017, month: 8, day: 20);
        var dateDay2 = new DateTime(year: 2017, month: 8, day: 21);
        var dateDay3 = new DateTime(year: 2017, month: 8, day: 22);
        var day1 = res.Days.Single(d => d.Date == dateDay1);
        var day2 = res.Days.Single(d => d.Date == dateDay2);
        var day3 = res.Days.Single(d => d.Date == dateDay3);

        //добавляем услуги в эти дни
        day1.Services.Add(serv1);
        day1.Services.Add(serv4);

        day2.Services.Add(serv3);
        day2.Services.Add(serv1);
        day2.Services.Add(serv2);

        day3.Services.Add(serv4);

        //запоминаем
        await dbService.Commit();
    }
}
```

Целиком пример можно скачать [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/dZSypB8J3M4fdQ).

Comment: Очень круто, спасибо большое!

Comment: Все круто. Одно маленькое дополнение - асинхронные методы лучше называть XxxAsync, чтоб было понятно сразу, кто тут асинхронный.

Comment: @tym32167 с этим делом наблюдаются разночтения. Некоторые рекомендуют добавлять в конец асинхр. методов постфикс Async, другие, особенно в последнее время, говорят, что это мол уже излишне, если только у вас в классе по соседству нет синхр.методов.

Comment: Ну, я не в курсе "рекомендаций" и "трендов", я человек простой - пишу асинхронный метод - добавляю постфикс. Потому глаз и зацепился :)

Comment: @tym32167 в крупном проекте, я соглашусь, что лучше бы писать так, чтоб другим коллегам было сразу ясно как работать с методами написанными вами, + "рука набита" на определенный стиль написания.