# Generic Repository. В DbSet<TEntity> : --- > 'Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Скриншот ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Контроллер:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string name)
{
    Company company = new Company
    {
        Name = name
    };

    companyRepository.Create(company);


    return View();
}
```

**Бизнес сущность:**

```
  public class Company
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**IRepository:**

```
interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{

    void Create(TEntity item);
    void Update(TEntity item);
    void Delete(TEntity item);
}
```

**Класс, который реализует IRepository:**

```
 public class OrgRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        public DbContext _context;
        public DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;


        public void Create(TEntity item)
        {
            _dbSet.Add(item);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }


        public void Delete(TEntity item)
        {
            _dbSet.Remove(item);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Update(TEntity item)
        {
            _context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Из фронтенда передается name. Проверял в дебагире.

Comment: У вас в ошибке явно написано, что _dbSet was null, где и чем инициализируются _context и _dbSet? Добавьте конструктор OrgRepository в вопрос

Comment: Для чего _dbSet - public?

Comment: Вот [пример посмотрите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/706805/222542). Обратите внимание на передачу контекста в репозиторий через конструктор.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я ссылку оставил в ответе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Передаем контекст репозитория через конструктор. Сначала создаем конструктор:

```
protected readonly DbContext _context;
    DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    public OrgRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
```

2) Потом передаем контекст в контроллере

```
ApplicationContext application = new ApplicationContext();
        OrgRepository<Company> companyRepository = new OrgRepository<Company>(new ApplicationContext());
        OrgRepository<Phone> phoneRepository = new OrgRepository<Phone>(new ApplicationContext());
```

**Более подробные исходники:**

1)[Как правильно организовать работу с данными (C# Desktop App, Database)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706271/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-c-desktop-app-database/706805#706805)

2) https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.13.php