# Реализация шаблона Репозиторий для работы с БД

Tags: c#, .net

Нужно реализовать набор классов для работы с СУБД.

Хочу реализовать шаблон Репозиторий.

Сначала я описываю сущности в виде классов, которые наследую от IRepository.

На этом этапе все ясно.

После того, как я описал все сущности по всей видимости мне их нужно сгруппировать в некоторую общую сущность, которая отвечает за соединение с БД и вот тут возникают вопросы...

Пришел вот к такой иерархии:

```
 public class Entity
{

    public int PrimaryKey;

}
public class Repository
{
    protected DbConnection Context;

    protected Repository(DbConnection context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }
}

interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity
{
    void Insert(TEntity entity);
    void Update(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
}

public class BookRepository : Repository, IRepository<Book>
{
    public BookRepository(DbConnection context) : base(context){}

    public void Insert(Book entity) { }

    public void Update(Book entity) { }

    public void Delete(Book entity) { }
}
public class Book : Entity
{

    public Book() { }
}

public class BookMarketRepositoy : Repository, IRepository<BookMarket>
{
    public BookMarketRepositoy(DbConnection context) : base(context){}

    public void Insert(BookMarket entity) { }


    public void Update(BookMarket entity) { }


    public void Delete(BookMarket entity) { }

}
public class BookMarket : Entity
{
    public BookMarket() { }
}

public class DbContext
{
    private DbConnection _conn;
    public BookMarketRepositoy BookMarkets { get; private set; }
    public BookRepository Books { get; private set; }

    public DbContext(DbConnection conn)
    {
        _conn = conn;
        if (_conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            _conn.Open();
        }
        BookMarkets = new BookMarketRepositoy(conn);
        Books = new BookRepository(conn);
    }
}
```

Похоже ли реализация на правду или можно сделать иначе и лучше?

Готовое ORM использовать не хочется, так как схема данных и набор оперций примитивна.

Comment: `Сначала я описываю сущности в виде классов, которые наследую от IRepository.` зачем?

Comment: Я когда то делал подобное ( [Entity](https://github.com/tym32167/webapisample/blob/master/src/Sample.Core/Contracts/IEntity.cs), [Repository](https://github.com/tym32167/webapisample/blob/master/src/Sample.Core/Repository/BaseRepository.cs) )

Comment: @tym32167, С этим особо проблем нету. Мне бы пример агрегации репозиториев в контексте БД.

Comment: Книга является репозиторием книг?

Comment: так у вас сущности являются репозиториями по сути, а вы говорите проблем нет. Вот захотите получить из БД 500 книг - это вы хотите иметь 500 ссылок на дата контекст при этом?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Да...

Comment: @tym32167, Кажется я понял. Сейчас поправлю и обновлю вопрос.

Comment: Посмотрите [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/706805/222542) с `Repository`&`UnitOfWork`

Comment: @tym32167 А такая иерархия похожа на правду?

Comment: Посмотрите хороший пример реализации [https://github.com/EduardoPires/EquinoxProject](https://github.com/EduardoPires/EquinoxProject)

Comment: Мне кажется, вам надо отталкиваться от юзкейсов, а то вы пишете код ради кода. Вам обязательно надо отдельный репозиторий на сущность? Вам обязательно нужны все эти методы CRUD в каждом репозитории? Вам точно не понадобится Unit of work? А что делать будете, если понадобится транзакция на несколько репозиториев? Шарить соединение? Как вы это планируете делать? Я предлагаю сперва подумать ЧТО вы хотите получить, а потом уже думать КАК написать код для этого.

Comment: не знаю как было в оригинале вопроса, но после правки вполне себе верно для "делаем для проекта. а не общее решение"

Answer (score 3):

Я бы посоветовал написать generic репозиторий вместе с UnitOfWork. Для этого сначала выделим интерфейс репозитория и базовую сущность модели:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IRepository<T>
    where T : Entity
{
    void Add(T entity);

    void Remove(T entity);

    IQueryable<T> Get();

    Task<T> GetAsync(int id);
}
```

Теперь нужно создать реализацию для этого репозитория. Поскольку мы пользуемся EF, то создадим реализацию на основе DbSet:

```
internal sealed class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : Entity
{
    private readonly DbSet<T> dbSet;

    public Repository(DbSet<T> dbSet)
    {
        this.dbSet = dbSet;
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Get()
    {
        return dbSet;
    }

    public Task<T> GetAsync(int id)
    {
        return dbSet.SingleAsync(e => e.Id == id);
    }

    public void Remove(T entity)
    {
        dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }
}
```

Теперь нужно создать сущность, которая будет предоставлять нам репозитории для любого типа. Это и есть UnitOfWork:

```
internal sealed class UnitOfWork // Dispose context
{
    private readonly DbContext context;
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> repositories;

    public UnitOfWork(DbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    }

    public IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>()
        where T : Entity
    {
        object result;
        if (repositories.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out result))
        {
            return (IRepository<T>)result;
        }

        var newRepository = new Repository<T>(context.Set<T>());
        repositories[typeof(T)] = newRepository;
        return newRepository;
    }

    public Task SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Теперь напишем небольшой пример. Сначала определим сущность "книга", а потом поработаем с этой сущностью через наш репозиторий:

```
public class Book : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }
}

using (var dbContext = new DbContext(""))
using (var uof = new UnitOfWork(dbContext))
{
    // достаем все книги Толкина
    var books = await uof
        .GetRepository<Book>()               // получили репозиторий
        .Get()                               // получили queryable
        .Where(b => b.Author == "Tolkien")   // отфильтровали
        .ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken);    // выполнили запрос и получили результаты

    // добавляем книгу Лема и сохраняем изменения
    var newBook = new Book
    {
        Author = "Lem",
        Name = "Solaris"
    };

    uof.GetRepository<Book>().Add(newBook);

    await uof.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: По поводу EF - автор пишет: `Готовое ORM использовать не хочется`

Comment: Не очень ясно, чем отличается ваш вариант от [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706271/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-c-desktop-app-database/706805#706805)?

Comment: @tym32167, в том варианте репозитории для отдельных типов выставлены как свойства. Здесь же выставлен generic метод для получения репозитория сущностей нужного типа. Автор использует DbContext в своем примере. Я предположил, что он неправильно понимает термин ORM. Ну и хотелось размять мозг и написать код :) зы. С контекстом промашка - он самописный

Comment: ха, про словарь я проглядел. А почему обычный словарь? UoW не сможет жеж с многопоточностью работать с такой реализацией.

Comment: @tym32167, не сможет. Ну так и DbContext не умеет работать с многопоточностью. Поэтому нет смысла втыкать ConcurrentDictionary.

Comment: Понял, спасибо :)