# Как реализовать комплексные операции в EF без возможности потери согласованности базы?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, архитектура, чистый-код, entity-framework-core

Допустим у меня есть таблицы

- топики `Topic`
  (тема, текст, автор, дата, ссылка на последнее сообщение)
- сообщения `Message`
  (текст, автор, дата)

когда пользователь пишет новое сообщение в топик мне в записи топика надо обновить поле ссылку на последнее сообщение.

Я вот думаю как правильно реализовать эту операцию. Дело в том что контекст базы данных ApplicationDbContext у меня много откуда доступен. Кто-то может взять и напрямую туда добавить сообщение, в этом случае ссылка на последнее сообщение в топике не обновится, и получится нарушение согласованности данных.

Как правильно организовать код, что бы по-максимуму исключить возможность нарушить согласованность базы, при этом код был красивый.

Может быть можно как-то обработчик повесить на добавление записи в таблицу? На стороне SQL Serve можно триггеры делать, можно ли что-то подобное делать на стороне EntityFramework?

Как я пока вижу решение этой задачи.

Сделать в самом `ApplicationDbContext` функцию добавления сообщения (как я сейчас и делаю).

```
ApplicationDbContext.AddMessage(Message message);
```

Правда это никак не помешает программисту вызвать `db.Messages.Add` и всё же нарушить согласованность базы. То есть программисту надо будет знать о том что сообщения надо добавлять через Спец. функцию а не через встроенную функциональность EF.

Можно ещё попробовать наследоваться например от `DbSet<Message>`, но так ещё не пробовал.

Как вы решаете подобные задачи?

**Добавлено:**

Так же я прекрасно понимаю что для таких задач можно использовать паттерн репозитория.

MessageRepository

- Find
- Delete
- Update
- Add

Но мне это в чисто таком виде не подходит, так как я использую сложные linq выборки, вот пример такой выборки:

```
threadViewModel.Materials = materialsQuery.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastActivity)


.Select(x => new TopicInfoViewModel()
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Title = x.Title,
    MessagesCount = x.Messages.Count(m=>!m.IsDeleted),
    AuthorName = x.Author.UserName,
    PublishDate = x.PublishDate,
    LastMessageId = x.LastMessageId,
    LastMessagePublishDate =
        x.LastMessageId.HasValue ? (DateTime?) x.LastMessage.PublishDate : null,
    CategoryName = x.Category.Name,
    LastMessageAuthorName = x.LastMessage.Author.UserName
})
```

Как видно из примера я не просто получаю элемент, но и данные из смежных таблиц, в том числе и агрегированные.

Просто find этого не сделает, а если и сделает, то запрос будет огромным и некрасивым, а так же будет работать дольше.

Как совместить красивые и эффективные linq выборки с репозиторием я не знаю.

Пока писал подумал что я linq использую только для выборки, и можно для выборок использовать `DbContext` а для редактирования репозиторий.  Надо подумать как это можно красиво совместить. Либо как-то прокинуть в репозиторий возможность делать выборки через linq.

Comment: А почему нужно работать напрямую с DbContext? У вас разве нет классов репозитория на каждую сущность?

Comment: @Bulson у меня нет, это как раз один из моментов, которые я хочу опнять о целесообразности использования репозитория.

Comment: Что, простите? Понять? Посмотрите [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/706805/222542), например.

Comment: @Bulson я понимаю что такое паттерн репозитория, просто не уверен в его нужности для себя, я в своём проекте использую для выборки из базы сложные вложенные linq запросы, которые берут данные сразу из разных таблиц, эти запросы синтаксически короткие и красивые, но они достигаются за счёт мощи linq, а в репозитории с простым find я не знаю как делать такие запросы и можно ли.

Comment: Тогда в репозитории нужно переходить на использование expressions, типа `IEnumerable<T> GetAll<TIncludeField>(Expression<Func<T, ICollection<TIncludeField>>> include);`

Comment: @Bulson можно поподробнее, если как-то сделать возможность использовать linq для выборки для репозитория это решит мою проблему, но пока не понял как это сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Путь падавана заключается в том, чтобы навесить триггер на базу. Триггер нужно создать в миграции, вызвав метод [`MigrationBuilder.Sql`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.sql?view=efcore-2.0).

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("CREATE TRIGGER ...");
```

Путь постигшего Дао заключается в том, чтобы разделять приложение на уровни и скрывать реализацию. Если сторонний программист работает с базой, скрой базу за паттерном *Хранилище* (в *Repository*) и обращайся к `ApplicationDbContext` только оттуда. Сторонний программист сможет добавить сообщение, только вызывав метод Хранилища сообщений, и не сможет ничего сломать.

**UPDATE**

Паттерн *Хранилище* не означает, что вы можете использовать только одну операцию `Find`. Он означает, что вы не уточняете сверх необходимого способ хранения бизнес-сущностей. *Хранилище* с точки зрения бизнес-логики это такая сверхбольшая коллекция сущностей, с которой невозможно работать целиком, поэтому вам нужно извлекать из неё либо единичные сущности, либо небольшие подколлекции.

Методы *Хранилища* определяет бизнес-логика, которую задаёт Заказчик. Например:

```
public IReadOnlyCollection<Message> ReadAllPopularMessages(int minPopularity, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{
    return dbContext.Messages
                    .Include(x => x.Author)
                    .OrderDescending(x => x.Popularity)
                    .Skip(pageSize * (pageNumber - 1))
                    .Take(pageSize)
                    .ToArray();
}
```

Внутри вы пользуете всю мощь LINQ, а снаружи даёте программисту бизнес-логики только то, что ему реально нужно.

Comment: Да, это решение мне понятно, но у него есть и свои минусы, основной минус в том что DbContext предоставляет из коробки такую функциональность, которую в хранилище не сделаешь, либо очень сложно и долго.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Падаван пишет в программе сложное регулярное выражение, чтобы продемонстрировать, что он умеет. Мастер Дао пишет три простые строки кода. Паттерн Хранилище позволяет Программисту ответственно подойти к разработке интерфейсов. Заказчик рассказывает Пользовательские истории, Программист понимает, что должно быть в интерфейсе Хранилищ, и реализует именно это. Такое самоограничение даёт свободу впоследствии.

Comment: Получается для каждого действия контроллера мне придётся добавлять методы в репозиторий... Как вариант да, подходит, но пока не уверен что мне нравится мысль скидывать все выборки в репозиторий. В любом случае (+), так как мне это помогает в расстановки по полочкам разных вариантов.

Comment: Обычно как я знаю такие сложные запросы выкидываются в `Service` классы `MessageService` в данном случае, а не в сам репозиторий. И эти классы образуют `Service` слой над репозиторием.

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент для себя нашёл такое решение.

Использовать паттерн репозиторий, подробнее можно почитать тут - [Generic Repository](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.13.php).

При этом в нём будет метод `Where` с той же сигнатурой как и метод `Where` из `Linq`.
Этот метод будет вызывать аналогичный метод `Where` из `DbContext` напрямую.
Таким образом я получу возможность делать любые сложные выборки через Linq.

Кроме того добавлю в него `Include` функциональность.

Пример использования может быть такой

```
messageRepository.Where(x=>x.Data >= minDate && x.Date <= maxDate)
    .Skip(10).Take(5).Select( x => new { .... })
```